# Java Rest call with jquery and ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest

I am making a ajax Rest call within jquery and it is supposed to return me a list of beans, which I want to show in the jsp. I am able to make the Rest call but I can't get how to get the result in the ajax call and show it in page.

jsp page with the ajax call

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#abcForm').submit(function(){
        var v = $('#abc').val();

        $.ajax({ 
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "jsonp",
           url: "http://localhost:8080/RestTest/rest/hello/"+v,

       }); 
     });
   });
</script>
```

java code

```
@Path("hello")
public class RestController {

@GET
@Path("{param}")

public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

    String output = "Hello : " + msg;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}

}
```

So actually there will be a rest call from the java class and it will return a list which needs to be shown in the jsp page as ajax call. This is where I am stuck.

Help needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a `success` callback that will be called when the request finishes as successful and will receive the response as the first parameter:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/RestTest/rest/hello/"+v,
    success: function(data) {
        //do something with data.
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried the `callback success` function and did alert on the data , but its not showing with this code